# Textbox 'this.value' stops JavaScript with single quotes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, escaping

I cannot get single quotes to work in JavaScript `this.value`. Double quotes work fine. I tried to use `escape()` and it didn't work and I cannot think of a way to use PHP to fix this, so does anyone else have any ideas?

```
function editItemInCart(newValue,fieldName,itemNum,cnt) {
    //alert(newValue);
    if (count == cnt) {
        count = 0;
        jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "editItem.html",
        data: "newvalue=" + escape(newValue) + "&fieldname=" + fieldName + "&itemNum=" + itemNum,
     })
     document.getElementById('status' + itemNum).innerHTML = "SAVED";
      jQuery("#status" + itemNum).show();
     setTimeout("fade_out('"+itemNum+"')", 1000);
    }
    //alert(newValue + fieldName + itemNum);
}

if ($cart['title'] != "")
        echo "<label>Title: </label> <input type=\"text\" onKeyUp=\"doEditItemInCart(this.value,'title',".$itemNum.")\" onChange=\"editItemInCart(this.value,'title',".$itemNum.")\" value=\"".htmlspecialchars($cart['title'])."\"><br />";


function doEditItemInCart(newValue,fieldName,itemNum) {
    count++;
    setTimeout("editItemInCart(escape('"+newValue+"'),'"+fieldName+"',"+itemNum+","+count+")",200);
}
```

Comment: what exactly i the problem? why do u need single quotes? what doesnt work?

Comment: It looks as though you've mixed PHP code with your JavaScript. Is this supposed to be PHP or JS?

Comment: @Johnny: The problem is that users can put in whatever they want in that input box. Since they can, they do, which includes special characters.

Comment: @whatgoodisaroad: This is really a javascript issue, the php is doing nothing but echoing and accepting the javascript ajax.

Comment: in the editItemInCart function, using javascript, you need to validate the this.value that you passed before doing the ajax call.  dont validate with php.

Comment: @Johnny: thats what i want to do, but I cannot seem to get it to validate at all. any ideas on this?

Comment: For anyone that comes later:
newValue = newValue.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
did it for me

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",
            url: "editItem.html?newvalue=" + escape(newValue) + "&fieldname=" + fieldName + "&itemNum=" +   itemNum,
         })
```

it also appears that you are setting the status of saved regardless of the ajax response. i suggest added an ajax success function
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The only problem is I WANT people to be able to use single quotes if they want, I just do not want the javascript to choke on it.

Comment: yes, but the string will be escaped before then. Javascript just has to handle it and pass it along.

Comment: then the problem is somewhere else, i send ajax calls that contain a tick all the time. i will make a new edit above to how i pass my data

Comment: That still doesnt work but I did realize I forgot a function in my example above, so maybe that will help.

Comment: for all those that come later: newValue = newValue.replace(/'/g, "\\'"); did it for me